# Javascript Replace() and innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have this code: [it is a rough example with poor coding, but it illustrates what I want to do.]

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function fun()
    {
       var divs = document.getElementById('hi');
       divs.innerHTML = divs.innerHTML.replace("cake","jump");
       alert(divs.innerHTML);
    }

    </script>

    <div id="hi">
       <span onclick="fun('cake');">Mer<span onclick="fun('cake');">Mer</span></span>
    </div>
    <a onclick='fun()';)>Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the `<a>` i want to change the onclick parameter within fun() from 'cake' to 'jump'.  I do not want to use the setAttribute() method as my real example has several nested tags and I want to replace 'cake' in several different places.

I want the innerHTML.replace() function to work to do this but, alas it doesn't function as I want it to.  How do I replace text within innerHTML?

Comment: You said it is not functioning the way you want it to. What is it doing?

Comment: What should happen when one clicks on a "Mer"?

Answer (score 3):

Forget it. Never hack around with the `innerHTML`, there's no guarantee it will be in any particular format, you're very likely to mess up the markup by replacing the wrong thing, and even if it works, you're serialising the document content into a string, hacking it and then recreating the entire content from the string again, instead of just replacing a particular thing you're interested in. This is slow and loses all non-serialisable data (like form field values, JS references and assigned event handlers).

In general DOM methods are much more reliable for altering page content. It's what they were designed for. Use them, and use the DOM Level 1 HTML properties in preference to `setAttribute` which is badly broken in IE. This goes double for event handler attributes. Trying to hack at JavaScript code *inside* an attribute value *inside* an HTML string is insanity, even if it worked.

There is no need whatsoever to replace any page content. You could implement your example much more easily with a simple variable:

```
<div id="hi">
   <span>Mer<span>Mer</span></span>
</div>
<a id="foo">Click</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var potato= 'cake';

    document.getElementById('foo').onclick= function() {
        potato= 'jump';
        return false;
    };

    var spans= document.getElementById('hi').getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i= spans.length; i-->0;) {

        spans[i].onclick= function() {
            alert(potato); // do whatever with the variable
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have an error in your HTML:

```
<a onclick='fun()';)>Click</a>
```

What's with the `;)` *outside the attribute value*?

Next...

> [...] method as my real example has several nested tags and I want to replace 'cake' in several different places.

This means you really, *really* don't want to use `innerHTML` and `replace()`. It **will** screw up. Use an HTML parser of sorts; walk the DOM recursively... anything other than `replace`.

Within the scope of your specific example, I suggest using a variable to hold the value of `cake` and `jump` instead.

Comment: "What's with the ;) outside the attribute value?" it's obviously a winky-face.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `replace` call to use the [RegEx "global"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) flag:

```
divs.innerHTML = divs.innerHTML.replace(/cake/g,"jump");
```

That said, if you're using this for more than a quick test, you should use DOM objects to accomplish what you would like to do.  Otherwise, this will get ugly really fast.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to change your `<a>` tag code:

```
<a onclick='fun(); return false;')>Click</a>
```

(The `return false;` is optional, but good practice.)

Comment: See Edit.  I forgot to add the second nested <span>.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change the onclick parameter is to make it a variable instead of a string literal. Here I'm using a variable called `food`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var food = "cake";

function change()
{
   food = "jump";
}

</script>

<div id="hi">
   <span onclick="alert(food);">Mer<span onclick="alert(food);">Mer</span></span>
</div>
<a onclick='change()'>Click</a>
```